# How to we monitor transactions in transit in the MQ on both sending and receiving side in Corda?

Tags: corda

We understand that there are port tear-down during transactions and different ports may be used when sending messages over to the counterparties. When a node goes down, the messages are still sent but they are being queued in the MQ, is there a recommended way how could we monitor these transactions/messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached this by finding the documents here: https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html#monitoring-your-node
where it illustrates Corda flow metrics visualized using hawtio.

I just needed to download and startup hawt.io and connect it to any ( or the specified node PID ) `net.corda.node.Corda` and by going to the JMX tab we could see the messages in queue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't currently monitor these messages.

This is because Artemis does not store its queued messages in a human-readable/queryable format. Instead, the queued messages are stored in the form of a high-performance journal that contains a lot of information that is required in case the message queue's state needs to be restored from a hard bounce.